# Code gets stuck, and doesn't know what to do next?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning python. I've been wanting to learn code for awhile now, and I'm finally in a place where I can. I watch online tutorials, and after a few hours of that. I go to this website called code combat just for fun.

But enough of that. Here is my code.

```
hero.moveRight()
hero.attack("Weak Door")
hero.say("C'Mon, Follow me!")

hero.moveRight(2)
hero.moveDown(2)
enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy() 
while True:
    if enemy:
        hero.attack(enemy) <----Line 10
    else:
        if not enemy:
        hero.moveXY(54, 22)
```

On Line 10 is when everything heads south. 
It gets stuck and the character on the game says "But its already dead, then acts confused.

I put in the "else:" to see if it fixed it, But it didn't.

Im really new to this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: We're going to need to see all the relevant code; ideally as an [mcve].

Comment: There doesn't seem anything in this code that would cause the `while` loop to terminate *or* find a new `enemy` after the current one is defeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy()` inside your `while` loop.

Such as:

```
...
hero.moveRight(2)
hero.moveDown(2)
while True:
    enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy() 
    if enemy:
        hero.attack(enemy) <----Line 10
    else:
...
```

Comment: Thanks George, That fixed that problem, but that also caused another error as well.
    else:
        if not enemy:
            hero.moveXY(54, 22)

it says, "Can't read protected Property "moveYX"

Comment: the command "if not enemy:" is useless... it is already inside of an 'else' that only gets executed whenever enemy is not a valid value... the error is due to the mis-indentation, simply delete this 'if' inside the 'else' and i'm pretty sure it will work

Comment: I fixed it! thanks.